# как вывести button на display

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как при нажатии button( ) вывести цифру на элемент display()
Так же как их добавлять, например вывел 1, при повторном нажатии добавить ещё 1(в итоге выйдет 2), и так далее, нажать на 10 и будет 11, на 20 и будет 21(Так скажем калькулятор, но только с действием +, так же без необходимости нажимать =)

Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Вопрос низкого качества. Приведите пример своего решения.

Comment: Что такое button() и display()? Нужен ваш код, с которым у вас возникли сложности

Comment: <div class="display">
            <input type="text" id="display">
            </div>
                <div class="butt">
                    <input type="button" value="1" id="one">
                    <input type="button" value="2" id="two">
                    <input type="button" value="5" id="three">
                    <input type="button" value="10" id="four">
                    <input type="button" value="50" id="five">
                    <input type="button" value="100" id="six">
                    <input type="button" value="X" id="x">
                </div>